# How to run a python script in the system using PHP in Windows

Tags: php, python, xampp

I have tried exec() and system() command to run the python script. Nothing seems to be working.

Basically, I'm using localhost to host a webpage. In the same system, there is a python script which I want to run using PHP(from a web page through a button). I do not want python code to be called to PHP to run, I want to run PHP code in the same system using the web interface(PHP)

PYTHON CODE:

```
import os
from os import mkdir, makedirs

bobo = r"C:\\AmeyoS3-Automated\\bobo_folder"
os.makedirs(bobo)
```

PHP CODE 1(Didn't work):

```
system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ameyo-selenium/temp/bobo.py")
```

PHP CODE 2(Didn't work):

```
$python = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe";
$file = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ameyo-selenium\temp\bobo.py";

$cmd = "$python $file";
exec("$cmd");
```

Python script works fine while running independently.
Problem is running the script through PHP Command.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Or did you enable errors? They could help more than us [I would assume 1- the space on directory name (because of syntax in system), 2- permission of php (such call can be restricted)

Comment: I guess space is the issue, coz it's working fine in other systems where python is installed in main C:/ directory instead of Program Files (x86)

Comment: In any case, try to identify where php write the logs: they are very important in case of bugs (and if you add warnings, you may discover some hidden errors).